# How can I add media queries like Tailwind to be in HTML but without Tailwind In React?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

For example : with Tailwind:
`<div className="md:hidden">Hello</div>`
will result the div hidden after the breakpoint md - which after Tailwind doc , it is 768px;
I would like to be able to do the same, but for custom widths, so not 768px;
And I Don't want to write it in the CSS file and I dont want to modify Tailwind files.
I would like to be still inline . Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#arbitrary-values)

> If you need to use a one-off breakpoint that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, use the min or max modifiers to generate custom breakpoint on the fly using any arbitrary value.

```
<div class="min-[320px]:text-center max-[600px]:bg-sky-300">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet jesus Thank you ! Edit: I would like to toggle classes , it doesnt seem to work this way

Comment: It should work like that

Comment: ``` <p className="header-l dark-color-text my-4 min-[200px]:text-white">
              Maximize skill, minimize budget
            </p>```  I swear it doesn't work

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `dark-color-text` overrides `text-white`. Is `dark-color-text` a custom class?

Comment: I've tried on other elements. il keep this method in mind; are there any other ways?

Comment: Works fine https://play.tailwindcss.com/NVcaJ1gLBt Finding another way because you can't find an error isn't the best thing to do